# How to plot hourly temperature data group by week in ggplot2?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot, dplyr

I have weather data collected in one-week-long experiments, with each week represented by the first day of the experiment, as shown below.

[image]

I want to create a graph to visualize hourly weather data within each week, where each column/line represents one hour's data for each week. To make x-axis similar to my experimental data figure, I added a `date2` column using `mutate(date2 = first(date))`. I had to create `date2` because the duration of the experiment was not exactly one week, I can't use `1 week` in `scale_x_date()`

I want a create a plot that resembles the following graph, but I'd like to plot hourly data rather than daily data. My data is already collected at hourly intervals.

[image]

My weather data looks like this

[image]

Here is the reproducible example

```
df <-
  structure(
    list(
      date = c(
        "05/26/2014 11:00 AM",
        "05/26/2014 12:00 PM",
        "05/26/2014 01:00 PM",
        "06/09/2014 12:00 PM",
        "06/09/2014 01:00 PM",
        "06/09/2014 02:00 PM",
        "06/16/2014 12:00 PM",
        "06/16/2014 01:00 PM",
        "06/16/2014 02:00 PM",
        "06/23/2014 12:00 PM",
        "06/23/2014 01:00 PM",
        "06/23/2014 02:00 PM",
        "06/30/2014 12:00 PM",
        "06/30/2014 01:00 PM",
        "06/30/2014 02:00 PM",
        "07/07/2014 12:00 PM",
        "07/07/2014 01:00 PM",
        "07/07/2014 02:00 PM",
        "07/14/2014 12:00 PM",
        "07/14/2014 01:00 PM",
        "07/14/2014 02:00 PM",
        "07/21/2014 12:00 PM",
        "07/21/2014 01:00 PM",
        "07/21/2014 02:00 PM",
        "07/28/2014 12:00 PM",
        "07/28/2014 01:00 PM",
        "07/28/2014 02:00 PM",
        "08/04/2014 12:00 PM",
        "08/04/2014 01:00 PM",
        "08/04/2014 02:00 PM",
        "08/11/2014 12:00 PM",
        "08/11/2014 01:00 PM",
        "08/11/2014 02:00 PM",
        "09/08/2014 12:00 PM",
        "09/08/2014 01:00 PM",
        "09/08/2014 02:00 PM",
        "09/15/2014 12:00 PM",
        "09/15/2014 01:00 PM",
        "09/15/2014 02:00 PM",
        "09/22/2014 12:00 PM",
        "09/22/2014 01:00 PM",
        "09/22/2014 02:00 PM",
        "09/29/2014 12:00 PM",
        "09/29/2014 01:00 PM",
        "09/29/2014 02:00 PM",
        "10/06/2014 12:00 PM",
        "10/06/2014 01:00 PM",
        "10/06/2014 02:00 PM",
        "10/13/2014 12:00 PM",
        "10/13/2014 01:00 PM",
        "10/13/2014 02:00 PM",
        "10/20/2014 12:00 PM",
        "10/20/2014 01:00 PM",
        "10/20/2014 02:00 PM",
        "10/27/2014 12:00 PM",
        "10/27/2014 01:00 PM",
        "10/27/2014 02:00 PM",
        "11/03/2014 12:00 PM",
        "11/03/2014 01:00 PM",
        "11/03/2014 02:00 PM"
      ),
      date2 = structure(
        c(
          1401104700,
          1401104700,
          1401104700,
          1402317900,
          1402317900,
          1402317900,
          1402920000,
          1402920000,
          1402920000,
          1403524800,
          1403524800,
          1403524800,
          1404129600,
          1404129600,
          1404129600,
          1404734400,
          1404734400,
          1404734400,
          1405339200,
          1405339200,
          1405339200,
          1405944000,
          1405944000,
          1405944000,
          1406548800,
          1406548800,
          1406548800,
          1407153600,
          1407153600,
          1407153600,
          1407758400,
          1407758400,
          1407758400,
          1410177600,
          1410177600,
          1410177600,
          1410782400,
          1410782400,
          1410782400,
          1411387200,
          1411387200,
          1411387200,
          1411992000,
          1411992000,
          1411992000,
          1412596800,
          1412596800,
          1412596800,
          1413201600,
          1413201600,
          1413201600,
          1413806400,
          1413806400,
          1413806400,
          1414411200,
          1414411200,
          1414411200,
          1415016000,
          1415016000,
          1415016000
        ),
        tzone = "UTC",
        class = c("POSIXct",
                  "POSIXt")
      ),
      week = structure(
        c(
          1L,
          1L,
          1L,
          2L,
          2L,
          2L,
          3L,
          3L,
          3L,
          4L,
          4L,
          4L,
          5L,
          5L,
          5L,
          6L,
          6L,
          6L,
          7L,
          7L,
          7L,
          8L,
          8L,
          8L,
          9L,
          9L,
          9L,
          10L,
          10L,
          10L,
          11L,
          11L,
          11L,
          12L,
          12L,
          12L,
          13L,
          13L,
          13L,
          14L,
          14L,
          14L,
          15L,
          15L,
          15L,
          16L,
          16L,
          16L,
          17L,
          17L,
          17L,
          18L,
          18L,
          18L,
          19L,
          19L,
          19L,
          20L,
          20L,
          20L
        ),
        levels = c(
          "1",
          "2",
          "3",
          "4",
          "5",
          "6",
          "7",
          "8",
          "9",
          "10",
          "11",
          "12",
          "13",
          "14",
          "15",
          "16",
          "17",
          "18",
          "19",
          "20",
          "21",
          "22",
          "23",
          "24",
          "25",
          "26"
        ),
        class = "factor"
      ),
      mean_temperature = c(
        25,
        25.25,
        26.075,
        26.2,
        26.35,
        27.65,
        29.95,
        29.4,
        30.5,
        22.75,
        24,
        25.275,
        25.6,
        26.8,
        27.125,
        27.5,
        27.525,
        26.1,
        30.65,
        30.65,
        30.425,
        26.15,
        24.5,
        23.7,
        25.65,
        25.85,
        25.2,
        26.975,
        27.125,
        28.275,
        18.55,
        18.775,
        19.125,
        18.8,
        20,
        19.375,
        17.825,
        17.925,
        18.25,
        18.975,
        20.825,
        20.1,
        18.1,
        18.4,
        19.2,
        16.325,
        18.4,
        18.75,
        14.675,
        14.925,
        15.3,
        15.9,
        17.175,
        17.525,
        22.45,
        23,
        23.475,
        17.8,
        18.05,
        17.725
      )
    ),
    class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl",
              "data.frame"),
    row.names = c(NA,-60L),
    groups = structure(
      list(
        week = structure(
          1:20,
          levels = c(
            "1",
            "2",
            "3",
            "4",
            "5",
            "6",
            "7",
            "8",
            "9",
            "10",
            "11",
            "12",
            "13",
            "14",
            "15",
            "16",
            "17",
            "18",
            "19",
            "20",
            "21",
            "22",
            "23",
            "24",
            "25",
            "26"
          ),
          class = "factor"
        ),
        .rows = structure(
          list(
            1:3,
            4:6,
            7:9,
            10:12,
            13:15,
            16:18,
            19:21,
            22:24,
            25:27,
            28:30,
            31:33,
            34:36,
            37:39,
            40:42,
            43:45,
            46:48,
            49:51,
            52:54,
            55:57,
            58:60
          ),
          ptype = integer(0),
          class = c("vctrs_list_of",
                    "vctrs_vctr", "list")
        )
      ),
      row.names = c(NA,-20L),
      .drop = TRUE,
      class = c("tbl_df",
                "tbl", "data.frame")
    )
  )
```

**EDIT**

Column graph are not appropriate to plot hourly temperature data because every data point starts from zero, and I don't have zeros in my data. Appropriate graph would be point or line graph as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72127566/how-to-plot-average-temperature-and-variation) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636733/r-ggplot2-plotting-hourly-data)

[image]

[image]

Comment: So you want an x axis from 0 to 24? And each week how?

Comment: The data is not properly copied and pasted, I'm getting an error when trying to reproduce it in my R session, `Error: C stack usage  15927504 is too close to the limit`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas My apologies. I have copied the data again. Should be okay now.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?
Extract `hour` from `date`, coerce the former to factor and the latter to a date object. Then plot grouping by `hour`. The y axis breaks by week.

Note that I process the `date` one step at a time in order to make it more readable and easier to debug, if needed.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(lubridate)
  library(ggplot2)
})

df %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(
    date = mdy_hm(date),
    hour = hour(date),
    date = ymd(format(date, "%Y-%m-%d")),
    hour = factor(hour)
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(date, mean_temperature, group = hour)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(), fill = "steelblue", color = "white") +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 week") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-07-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

To remove the days without measurements, coerce the x-axis variable, `date`, to factor and remove the x-axis date scale.

Note that I have kept the white line separation between bars, to remove it remove `color = "white"` from `geom_col`.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(lubridate)
  library(ggplot2)
})

df %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(
    date = mdy_hm(date),
    hour = hour(date),
    date = ymd(format(date, "%Y-%m-%d")),
    date = factor(date),
    hour = factor(hour)
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(date, mean_temperature, group = hour)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(), fill = "steelblue", color = "white") +
  labs(x = "Date", y = "Mean temperature") +
  # coord_flip() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-07-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: @Ahsk I don't understand, you are saying that the bars shouldn't start at 0?

Comment: Yes, the bars should correspond to the actual range of temperature in that hour. If the starts bars at zero then that would mean zero temperature in that hour, right? .The data is recorded at hourly interval and there is no zero is the `mean_temperature` column, but the bars are starting at zero.

Comment: @Ahsk No, I believe you are wrong, the bars should start at zero. What can be misleading is to have a bar plot starting at a fluid point, in this case the data minimum. Though this is not the case, it would make it easier to manipulate the plots, have the origin change and the bars will look smaller or bigger at will.